# Use Bootstrap Carousel for latest-tweets-php-o-auth

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, oauth, carousel, tweets

Andrew Biggart's latest-tweets-php-o-auth is one of the best Twitter tools by far,
I would display the tweets with the Bootstrap Carousel:

Here the latest-tweets-php-o-auth function:

```
function display_latest_tweets(

        // Function parameters.

        $tweet_wrap_open     = '<li class="item"><p class="home-tweet-tweet">',
```

where:

```
// Render the tweet.
                            $twitter_html .= $tweet_wrap_open.html_entity_decode($tweet_desc).$meta_wrap_open.'<a href="http://twitter.com/'.$twitter_user_id.'">'.$display_time.'</a>'.$meta_wrap_close.$tweet_wrap_close;
```

assuming I'm gonna have multiple li.item (tweets), in order to use the Bootstrap Carousel it needs the class "active" on the first...

How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the parameters to include the carousel id and classes:

```
// Function parameters.

$twitter_wrap_open   = '<div id="tweet" class="carousel slide"><div class="carousel-inner home-tweets-ul">',
$twitter_wrap_close  = '</div></div>',
```

Add the active class to the item with jQuery at the end/in the footer:

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#tweet .item:first").addClass("active");
        jQuery('#tweet').carousel({
            interval: 5000
        });
    });
</script>
```